# How to update a layout into a Python Dash application

Tags: python, layout, callback, plotly-dash

i'm new with Python & Dash and i don't know how to force my application to refresh the shown layout without use the callback; this is my code:

***AppMain.py***

```
app.layout = html.Div(
children=[
    dcc.Location(
        id=ID_URL,
        refresh=False
    ),
    html.Div(
        [
            dcc.Link(
                'Test',
                href=HREF_PAGE_TEST,
            ),
            dcc.Link(
                'Single',
                href=HREF_PAGE_SINGLE,
            ),
            dcc.Link(
                'Common',
                href=HREF_PAGE_COMMON,
            ),
        ]
    ),
    html.Div(
        id=ID_PAGE_CONTAINER,
    ),
),


@app.callback(
     Output(ID_PAGE_CONTAINER, 'children'),
     [Input(ID_URL, 'pathname')],
)
def clickOnPageToShow(pathname):
     return findPageToShow(pathname)

def findPageToShow(pathname):
    if pathname == HREF_PAGE_TEST:
        PageTest.data_frame = shared_data_frame
        return PageTest.layout

    elif pathname == HREF_PAGE_SINGLE:
        PageSingle.data_frame = shared_data_frame
        return PageSingle.layout

    elif pathname == HREF_PAGE_COMMON:
        PageCommon.data_frame = shared_data_frame
        return PageCommon.layout

    return ""
```

Every page builds own layout and user choose which one shown clicking on the related dcc.Link; this procedure works fine and user can change page avery time he wants.

What i want now is to build and shown the PageSingle in programmatically way, so i tried to add:

```
AppMain.showPageSingle()
```

and

```
def showPageSingle():
    page = findPageToShow(HREF_PAGE_SINGLE)
    app.layout[ID_PAGE_CONTAINER].children = [page]
    #app.layout[ID_PAGE_CONTAINER].children = page
```

But nothing happens.

What i do wrong?
Thanks

***EDIT***

How suggested i use a callback raised when use click on a cell of table created into page *Common*

***PageCommon.py***

```
@app.callback(
    Output(ID_PAGE_CONTAINER, 'children'),
    [
        Input(ID_TABLE_COMMON, 'active_cell'),
        Input(ID_TABLE_COMMON, 'data')
    ]
)
def clickOnCell(active_cell, data_table):

    if active_cell is not None:
        row_index = active_cell['row']
        col_index = active_cell['column']

        import AppMain
        return AppMain.buildPageSingle()

    return []
```

**BUT** in this case, application doesn't respond when i choose a page, maybe because the callback is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an "interval" component in this way (in your layout):

```
   dcc.Interval(
            id='interval-component',
            interval=60 * 1000,  # in milliseconds , 20 seconds every refresh
            n_intervals=0
```

And then, you can refer to that component.

```
@app.callback(Output('live-update-time', 'children'),
             [Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')])

def update_time(n):
    current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    return html.P(f"Last Update at {current_time} ")
```

In the above example, i refresh my page every 20 second.

Comment: Hi & Thanks. 
I ve seen this kind of solution but i don't want to refresh periodically the page; this update must be done only when user do certain actions.

Comment: If you need to refer to an user's action, you probably need a callback....

Comment: Yes, i edited the question to explain my problem with the callback